# Vagrant: Debug Slow Starting VM

Tags: vagrant

I'm using vagrant to setup a virtual environment on a programming project. Virtual Box is the VM provider. I'm working on a Windows workstation.  This is borderline server fault territory -- but since I'm using vagrant to setup an environment for a programming project I'm asking on Stack Overflow.

When I run

```
vagrant up
```

Vagrant can take "a long time" (up to 5 minutes) to start the virtual machine.  From my side (starting vagrant from a "Git Bash" shell) I see this

```
default: SSH auth method: private key
default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
default: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
```

This continues for a while, and the server eventually comes up. Also, occasionally, the SSH connection will die between 12 - 24 hours after I do a `vgrant up` -- this forces a `halt -f`/re-up.

If I start the machine from Virtual Box itself, here's the relevant section of the start up routine.

[image]

The halting seems to happen when this screen reads

> Waiting 10 Seconds for a Network Device
>
> Waiting 120 Seconds for a Network Device

This seems abnormal (and certainly annoying) behavior and I'd like to debug why it's happening -- However, I'm not familiar enough with the workings of vagarnt or virtual machines to know where I should start.  I'd love a magic solution to my problem, but all I'm really after is "where do I start digging"

Comment: this belongs on [sf]

Comment: @DanielA.White Are you sure?  I recall asking similar questions over there in the past and they pushed it back to Stack Overflow because it was about setting up a programmers environment.  Is there official policy on this?

Comment: what if you dropped the term "programmers environment" and took it as a straight question of "why is vagrant doing this?"

Comment: @DanielA.White If I did that it'd be a less accurate description of what I was doing :)

Comment: @AlanStorm it seems to be a problem with cloud-init, so I would start your troubleshooting there. Also you could post your Vagrantfile here (or at least a minimally reproducible test case) to see if others have further ideas.